# Condition for rank to be 2.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose that

$$\mbox{rank}\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
a & b & b & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} = 2$$

for some real numbers $a$ and $b$. What is the value of $b$?

- $0.3$
- $3$
- $1$
- $0.5$

I'm unable to get the condition on $b$ only.

Comment: One way is to look on the minors of the matrix. This can solve the problem but I don't know if it is the optimal approach.

Comment: I think it is good enough. This is the only method I have came across yet that gives a solution for b.

Answer (score 0):

For the rank to be $2$ the third row has to be a linear combination of the first two (since the first two are obviously linearly independent).

Then, if the two $b$s in the third row are equal, the coefficient of the *first* row must be $0$.

This leads to a value of $b$ that is not among the options, so there must be a bug in the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

has rank $2$ thus the closest answer is $ b=0.3$